# Avoid casting enums, instead using a static class with static members?

Tags: c#, enums

I want to avoid having to cast all my enums to the type `byte`.
`MyFunction` takes `byte` as argument. So when I want to pass an enum of my two enum types `MyEnum` and `MyOtherEnum` I would have to cast it to `byte` (As I do it when calling `MyFunction` in `Main`).
So what I would love to have is for my `MyFunction` to be able to pass `MyEnum` and `MyOtherEnum`values without casting. Like `MyFunction(MyEnum.FOO)`.
Is this possible with enums or do I have to declare a class for them with static members and getters?

This is my Code:

```
namespace myspace{

enum MyEnum{
FOO = 0x00,
BAR = 0x01
}
MyOtherEnum{
FOO2 = 1,
BAR2 = 3
}

class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MyFunction( (byte) MyEnum.FOO); //Casting necessary
      MyFunction( MyEnum.FOO);        // Would love to be able to do this...
      MyFunction( MyOtherEnum.FOO2);  // ...And this
    }

    MyFunction(byte value)
    {
      //do smth with value
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass different enums to one function?

Comment: Even if their base types matched the required parameter type, you still require an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you need to do this, but the easiest thing is just to write a set of wrappers:

```
MyFunction(MyEnum value)
{
   MyFunction((byte)value);
}
MyFunction(MyOtherEnum value)
{
   MyFunction((byte)value);
}
MyFunction(byte value)
{
  //do something with value
}
```

Comment: If possible, I'd prefer this method as well as with the `byte` version it means you could pass _any byte_ even if it made no sense in the context of the function. (EDIT: bonus if you can make the `byte` overload `private`)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - Yes, a very good point.  That's how I'd do it if I were writing it myself - `public` wrappers that all call a `private` version to do the processing.

Answer (score 0):

haven't checked by myself but try to master MyFunction using `System.Enum` instead of `byte`.

Another possible way is to use classes as enums:

```
public class MyEnum
{
   public const byte FOO = 0x00;
   public const byte BAR = 0x01;
}
```

and

```
public class MyOtherEnum
{
   public const byte FOO2 = 1;
   public const byte BAR2 = 3;
}
```

Now your code will eat

```
MyFunction(MyEnum.FOO);
MyFunction(MyOtherEnum.FOO2);
```

But in case you want to make it more like enum, make a base class for both and make sure it contains another byte value for current value.
In such case declare MyFunction like the following:

```
MyFunction(MyEnumBase value)
{
  //do smth with value
}
```

Hope it helped,
Yanir